# Утилита stace опция -k. Откуда берутся имена функций

Tags: c

Порция вывода команды strace -kyf bash -c ':'

> /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so(getegid+0xb) [0xcc91b]
> /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so(eaccess+0x84) [0xefa74]
> /usr/bin/bash(file_status+0xaf) [0x82b7f]
> /usr/bin/bash(file_status+0x537) [0x83007]
> /usr/bin/bash(initialize_shell_variables+0x24b) [0x461eb]
> /usr/bin/bash(_start+0x8ff) [0x221ef]
> /usr/bin/bash(main+0x95f) [0x209ff]
> /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so(__libc_start_main+0xd5) [0x27b25]
> /usr/bin/bash(_start+0x2e) [0x2191e]

Откуда берутся эти имена если вывод следующей команды пустой?

```
$ objdump -h $(which bash) | grep debug
```

---

Не понимаю откуда он берёт имена?

```
# include <stdio.h>
void show_hello ()
{
    printf("Hello Word\n");
}

int main ()
{
    show_hello();
}

$ gcc -Wall -g0 -fvisibility=hidden -o hello hello.c

$ strace -kf ./hello |& grep show_hello
 > /tmp/hello(show_hello+0x13) [0x114c]
 > /tmp/hello(show_hello+0x13) [0x114c]
 > /tmp/hello(show_hello+0x13) [0x114c]  

$ nm -D ./hello | grep show_hello # Нету
$ objdump -h ./hello | grep debug # Нету
```

Comment: И что, grep не находит секцию `.gnu_debuglink`? Отладочные символы могут находиться как в самом бинарнике, так и во внешнем файле. Если они находятся во внешнем файле, то вышеуказанная секция содержит имя этого файла и его crc32: [Debugging Information in Separate Files](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html)

Comment: Попробуйте запустить `gdb ls` - он при запуске должен показать откуда загружается отладочная информация. Или напишет, что её нет: `No debugging symbols found in /usr/bin/ls`

Comment: `$ objdump -h блоб` — это имена секций. а (те или иные) символы можно вывести с несколько другими опциями. см. `$ man objdump` на предмет, например, опций `-t` и `-T`.

Comment: Чтобы символов не было к `gcc -Wall -g0 -fvisibility=hidden -o hello hello.c`  надо еще добавить `-s` иначе они там в отладочных символах будут (`"nm" "./hello"`). А вообще следует ограничится одним вопросом в вопросе.

Comment: @study,  имена функций `strace` берет из таблицы символов. Посмотреть ее можно `objdump -t`, (а не `-h`, которая показывает имена **секций**). Подробнее, как всегда, в man objdump (и т.п.)

Answer (score 2):

Имена функций могут браться из таблицы импорта и экспорта. Причем таблицы экспорта бывают не только у библиотек, но и у исполняемых файлов. Ну и часто сборка происходит с visibility=default и поэтому в таблицу экспорта попадает все подряд, а не только интерфейс (с этим беда). Эту таблицу можно вывести выполнив `"nm" "-D" "/bin/bash"`